# How do I get Dropbox to do selective sync?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, mac, dropbox

I managed to set up selective sync in Dropbox once before but now I can't work out how I did it. I want to set Dropbox to "selective sync" so that I don't end up with all my personal files on my work computer.

I've got it running on Ubuntu, Windows 7, and Mac OSX 10.5.

Answer (score 6):

From Dropbox's "[What is Selective Sync](http://www.dropbox.com/help/175)":

**Windows:**

- Click on the Dropbox icon from the system tray
- Select Preferences
- Click the Advanced Tab
- Click the Selective Sync button

**Mac OS X and Linux:**

- Click the Dropbox icon from the menu bar
- Select Preferences
- Click the Advanced Tab
- Click the Selective Sync button

[image: dropbox settings]

[image: selective sync]

Comment: Note that he should also have Dropbox version 0.8 or higher. Previous versions don't have this feature

Comment: ah! that's the problem, my advanced tab isn't on this machine. Is it safe to update the dropbox software?

Comment: actually, how do i update dropbox, i can only find an install link on the website and it doesn't ask if i'm updating a previous version.

Comment: @Bec: Yes, it should be safe to update. I don't know why it wouldn't be.

Comment: can i do an update without deleting and reinstalling?

Comment: @Bec Reinstalling won't delete your files in your Dropbox folder.